# Automatic properties: DBSet vs ObjectSet

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

Why are we able to use automatic properties with `DBSet`, but not with `ObjectSet`:

```
public class SomeContext : DbContext
{        
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
             ...
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

DbContext is using convention over configuration paradigm. It discovers entity sets based on DbSet properties defined on the DbContext derived class (or in general, it discovers your model based on your code). ObjectContext does not do any discovery and is not convention based. It just reads your model from csdl, ssdl and msl artifacts. As a result ObjectContext requires that the user tells exactly what needs to be exposed.

Answer (score 5):

Simply because DbContext API is newer version created to provide simplified API for better development experience.